# Customers who likes banana but not apple - Improve Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

**What is the better way to get the same output?**

**I only want those customers who likes 'Banana' but not 'Apple'**

Example:

101, 102 and 108 likes both banana and apple so I don't want

105 likes apple so I don't want

106 doesn't like banana so I don't want

**EXPECTED RESULT SHOULD BE 103,104**,

```
DECLARE @SampleTable TABLE
    (
        CustomerNumber INT,
        Likes VARCHAR(20),
        Random VARCHAR(5)
    );

INSERT INTO @SampleTable (CustomerNumber, Likes, Random)
VALUES 
 (101, 'Banana', 'A'),
 (101, 'Orange', 'A'),
 (101, 'Melon', '1'),
 (101, 'Apple', 's'),
 (102, 'Banana', 'f'),
 (102, 'Apple', 'g'),
 (103, 'Banana', 'h'),
 (103, 'Melon', 'j'),
 (104, 'Banana', 'A'),
 (104, 'Mango', '1'),
 (105, 'Apple', 's'),
 (106, 'Grapes', 'f'),
 (107, 'Apple', 'g'),
 (108, 'Banana', 'h'),
 (108, 'Apple', 'j');

SELECT * FROM @SampleTable;

SELECT * FROM @SampleTable
WHERE CustomerNumber NOT IN
(SELECT CustomerNumber FROM @SampleTable WHERE Likes = 'Apple')
AND CustomerNumber IN
(SELECT CustomerNumber FROM @SampleTable WHERE Likes = 'Banana')
```

Comment: What make you think there is anything wrong with your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one condition directly thus removing one of sub-queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @SampleTable
WHERE Likes = 'Banana'
AND CustomerNumber NOT IN
(SELECT CustomerNumber FROM @SampleTable WHERE Likes = 'Apple')
```

Or do the same with `EXISTS` and correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SampleTable t1
WHERE Likes = 'Banana'
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 
 FROM SampleTable t2 WHERE t2.Likes = 'Apple' 
                       AND t1.CustomerNumber=t2.CustomerNumber);
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/934a2b/5) (based on MySQL)

Comment: @Stu - Thank you very much for the edit. I did not see the typo.

Comment: Your query is easy to understand and working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another way, but not necessarily better

```
with nuts as (
 select *,
  Max(case when likes='apple'  then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by customernumber) apple,
  Max(case when likes='banana' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by customernumber) banana
 from SampleTable
)
select customernumber, likes, random
from nuts
where banana=1 and apple=0
```